better UX for settings option has multi selection
I want better UX for setting has multi options with checkbox and every option has 2 options with radio button

Hi, welcome to UXSE!
This forum works best when you describe a specific problem you're dealing with, along with the larger context and constraints. It's also very helpful to have some mocks of the problem you're working on, and where you are in a proposed solution. That way the community can help you in a more informed manner.
